# how to disable automatic connection to a saved wi-fi network

Tags: java, android, android-wifi, wifimanager

I want to disable automatic connection and authentication to saved network and delegate these functions to program, but I didn't find API for this.
Automatic disconnection after connection or trying is not a solution, because client already generate and receive authentication frames, which can be used by badboy for WPA(2)-PSK password recognition.

Also I don't want to save connection parameters for networks in program and erase saved networks in standard wi-fi service.
Please tell me about API or code example for this task.